# где находятся переменная в стеке или в куче? передеписал вопрос

Tags: c, указатели, память

прошлый свой вопрос - тупанул в постановке задачи. сморозил абсурд. поэтому переписываю. вопрос прежний : где находятся `jjj->a` и `jjj->bbb` в стеке или в куче?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} myStruct;

myStruct* test() {
    myStruct zzz;
    zzz.a = 555;
    zzz.b = 111;
    myStruct* jjj = &zzz;

    return jjj;
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    myStruct* zzz = test();

    printf("%d %d", zzz->a, zzz->b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот здесь -

```
myStruct* test() {
    myStruct zzz;
    zzz.a = 555;
    zzz.b = 111;
    myStruct* jjj = &zzz;

    return jjj;
}
```

пока что (во время выполнения функции) в стеке. А вот здесь -

```
myStruct* zzz = test();
printf("%d %d", zzz->a, zzz->b);
```

уже по сути нигде. В области памяти в стеке, которая уже была отмечена как свободная (и может быть использована для хранения других данных, а может, уже и использована...).

Нельзя использовать адрес локальной переменной после выхода из функции - это типичное неопределенное поведение.

То, что вы получаете при выводе те же значения, которые записывали - ничего не значит. Как я уже писал в ответе на другой ваш вопрос - вы можете перебегать дорогу на красный свет светофора. Можете переходить ее с завязанными глазами и заткнутыми ушами. И у вас это будет отлично получаться... до поры до времени. Как в этом случае :)

Comment: это я уже понял и закрыл, а это уже другой вопрос.  забудьте о выходе из функции test. представьте , что мы находится в функции test и тут вопрос, где лежат jjj->a и jjj->bbb  ?

Comment: там же, где и zzz.a и zzz.bbb, так как `jjj == &zzz`. В данном случае в стеке. Но это ещё раз - в данном случае.

Comment: Ну я же написал - **пока что (во время выполнения функции) в стеке**. Там, где выделено место для `jjj` - выделено место для полей `a` и `b`.

Comment: Память zzz действительна до строчки `return jjj;`, после этого - стек наполняется служебными (или другими) данными, и zzz может быть стёрта с вероятностью 99.9%, поскольку данный участок считается сбободным. В некоторых случаях вы получите правильный ответ (пока программа маленькая), но в будущем похожие трюки приведут к проблеме "теряются данные".

Comment: @nick_n_a  а вот это уже нагнетания ситуации. Ну не будет там просто кто то так просто наполнять "служебными данными" и "стирать с вероятностью". Это с++, а не какая то джава/пхп - тут все достаточно детерминированно. В коде пише printf будет "портить объект, который лежит в стеке".

Comment: то есть работа с кучей только если есть malloc или new , все остальное стек. верно я понимаю ?

Comment: Ну, глобальные переменные могут лежать в сегменте памяти, отличном от стека и кучи, например...